# cannot see the label content when a item is selected from dynamically added dropdownlist

Tags: c#, asp.net, drop-down-menu

I have a Dropdownlist (DDL1) when I select any item from this dropdownlist(DDL1), results in creation of another dropdownlist(DDL2), This contains some of the items.When I select other Item from DDL1 , Items will change in DDL2, this happens for the each different item selected in DDL1.

when I select a item from DDL2, label content must be shown, intially I'm making Label invisibe and in the code I changed the visibility to true and added content to it. But the label content is not shown when I select a item from DDL2.

Here is my Code

```
protected void DropDownList1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
     if (DropDownList1.SelectedValue == "Abe Books")
    {
        DropDownSeller.Visible = true;
        lnkUsdBooks.Visible = true;
        lnkUsdBooks.Text = "usedbooks@abe.com";
        lnkUsdBooks.NavigateUrl = "mailto:usedbook@abe.com";
        DropDownSeller.Visible = true;
        DropDownSeller.Items.Remove("Chacha Choudary");
        DropDownSeller.Items.Remove("SpiderMan");
        DropDownSeller.Items.Remove("Amar chitra Katha");
        DropDownSeller.Items.Remove("Chandamama");
        DropDownSeller.Items.Remove("Mahabharata");
        DropDownSeller.Items.Add("Amar chitra Katha");
        DropDownSeller.Items.Add("Chandamama");
        DropDownSeller.Items.Add("Mahabharata");
        DropDownSeller.DataBind();

            if (DropDownSeller.SelectedValue == "Amar chitra Katha")
            {
                lblPrice.Visible = true;
                lblPrice.Text = "$69.99";
            }
            else if (DropDownSeller.SelectedValue == "Chandamama")
            {
                lblPrice.Visible = true;
                lblPrice.Text = "$59.99";
            }
            else if (DropDownSeller.SelectedValue == "Mahabharata")
            {
                lblPrice.Visible = true;
                lblPrice.Text = "$49.99";
            }
            else
            {
                lblPrice.Visible = false;
            }
        }
```

Any ideas on this are appreciated

Thanks,

Comment: "But the label content is not shown when I select a item from DDL2". And where is the code of that event?

Comment: You are adding items to `DropDownSeller` and checking to see if the item you just added is also selected?

Comment: @Bala R I have set the AutoPostBack Value to true

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove  `if (!Page.IsPostBack)` from the `DropDownList1_SelectedIndexChanged` because when the page postbacks this condition will be false. Because your page is posting back to the server that's why it is not visible and not showing.

In short your `DropDownList1_SelectedIndexChanged` should be like..

```
protected void DropDownList1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (DropDownList1.SelectedValue == "Abe Books")
    {
        DropDownSeller.Visible = true;
        lnkUsdBooks.Visible = true;
        lnkUsdBooks.Text = "usedbooks@abe.com";
        lnkUsdBooks.NavigateUrl = "mailto:usedbook@abe.com";
        DropDownSeller.Visible = true;

        DropDownSeller.Items.Clear(); // it will clear all the items, instead you are removing one by one

        DropDownSeller.Items.Add("Amar chitra Katha");
        DropDownSeller.Items.Add("Chandamama");
        DropDownSeller.Items.Add("Mahabharata");
        DropDownSeller.DataBind(); 
    }
    protected void DropDownSeller_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (DropDownSeller.SelectedValue == "Amar chitra Katha")
        {
            lblPrice.Visible = true;
            lblPrice.Text = "$69.99";
        }
        else if (DropDownSeller.SelectedValue == "Chandamama")
        {
            lblPrice.Visible = true;
            lblPrice.Text = "$59.99";
        }
        else if (DropDownSeller.SelectedValue == "Mahabharata")
        {
            lblPrice.Visible = true;
            lblPrice.Text = "$49.99";
        }
        else
        {
            lblPrice.Visible = false;
        } 
    }
```

Comment: Exactly as I was about to write. If you step through your code you would be able to see this.

Comment: I removed (!page.IsPostback) and still I cannot see the label content when I select the item from DDL2

Comment: I have edit my answer. try now. you have to use DropDownSeller Selected Index change, as you want to visible on DropDownSeller